# CONAN - error while compiling consumer: Cannot specify link libraries for target "MyLib" which is not built by this project

Tags: cmake, conan

I have a library MyLib/0.1@myself/testing that is uploaded to remote: myconan-test
I'm searching how to use it in a consumer with conanfile.py. The package is downloaded in cache after the installing step. But I have an error while compiling the consumer `Cannot specify link libraries for target "MyLib" which is not built by this  project.`  Could you explain the cause of my error? Thank you

My project

```
consumer_MyLib
|-conanfile.py
|-build
|-src
|    |-CMakeLists.txt
     |-example.cpp
```

My conanfile.py

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class ConsumeMyLibConan(ConanFile):
   settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
   requires = "MyLib/0.1@myself/testing"
   generators = "cmake", "gcc", "txt"

   def build(self):
      cmake = CMake(self)
      cmake.configure(source_folder="src")
      cmake.build()
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(consumer_MyLib CXX)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(${project_name} example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}  ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Steps that I did to compile:

```
mkdir build & cd build
conan install ..
conan build ..
```

The output error

```
[user@dev build]$ conan build ..
      Using lockfile: '/home/user/Projects/consumer_MyLib/build/conan.lock'
Using cached profile from lockfile
conanfile.py: Running build()
-- Conan: called by CMake conan helper
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Conan: Checking correct version: 4.8
-- Conan: C++ stdlib: libstdc++
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "MyLib" which is not built by this
  project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Projects/consumer_MyLib/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ERROR: conanfile.py: Error in build() method, line 15
        cmake.configure(source_folder="src")
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing cd '/home/user/Projects/consumer_MyLib/build' && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCONAN_IN_LOCAL_CACHE="OFF" -DCONAN_COMPILER="gcc" -DCONAN_COMPILER_VERSION="4.8" -DCONAN_CXX_FLAGS="-m64" -DCONAN_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-m64" -DCONAN_C_FLAGS="-m64" -DCONAN_LIBCXX="libstdc++" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/user/Projects/consumer_MyLib/build/package" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR="bin" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR="include" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR="share" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY="ON" -DCONAN_EXPORTED="1" -Wno-dev '/home/user/Projects/consumer_MyLib/src'
```

Comment: Name of the project is contained in [PROJECT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/PROJECT_NAME.html) variable. The variable `project_name` which you use is **empty** (CMake doesn't set it), so the call `add_executable(${project_name} example.cpp)` is effectively the same as `add_executable(example.cpp)` (without the first argument!) and call `target_link_libraries(${project_name}  ${CONAN_LIBS})` is effectively the same as `target_link_libraries(${CONAN_LIBS})` which leads you to the error.

Comment: It is very possible that the libstdc++ setting is not the correct one. Have you read the green "Important" notice in https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html? Or are you really using gcc 4.8? What is the profile that was used when you did ``conan install``?

Comment: Thank for your help. I can compile my project now. It was the variable PROJECT_NAME which cased the problem.